# Showing json data when host on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, mern

I did host mern project on heroku.. Home page working perfectly but when I switch to about or other pages and reload it, showing json data on web not UI.. Please help me what could be the problem

Live Website Url: https://rawat-portfolio.herokuapp.com/

[Code Structure][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVLGx.png

**App.js Code**

```
const upload = multer();
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "PRODUCTION") {
  require("dotenv").config({ path: "backend/config/config.env" });
}

const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: process.env.MONGODB_URL,
  collection: "sessions",
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "my secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: store,
  })
);

app.use(userRoutes);
app.use(projectRoutes);
// Middleware to handle errors
app.use(errorMiddleware);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "uploads")));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "PRODUCTION") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "frontend", "build")));

  app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "frontend", "build", "index.html")
    );
  });
}

module.exports = app;
```

**Server.js Code**

```
connectDatabase();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(
    `Server started on PORT: ${PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode`
  );
});

// unhandled promise rejection

process.on("unhandledRejection", (err) => {
  console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
  console.log("Shutting down the server due to unhandled promise rejection");
  process.exit();
});
```

Comment: Can you post a link to your website? You should also update your question to include your code, this way people might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

got the solution...

I named api's same as route/page name. just change the api's name and issue solved